# Extra space on top of UISearchController's UITableView

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I set up a `UISearchController` like this:

```c
    searchResultsController = SearchResultsController()

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchController.delegate = self
    definesPresentationContext = true

    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

`SearchResultsController` is just a view controller with `UITableView` to show search results.

When the device is in portrait, start searching in portrait mode, there is an extra space on top of the table view (the RESULT header is the start of table view)

[image: Device in portrait - Start search in portrait]

Then if I rotate to landscape mode, the space disappeared:

[image: Device in landscape - Start search in portrait]

When device is in landscape mode and I start search, then the table view is cut off:

[image: Device in landscape - Start search in landscape]

Then if I rotate to portrait, the table view fits perfectly:

[image: Device in portrait - Start search in landscape]

The extra space height is exactly same as status bar height. So I wonder there is something related to the status bar here.

This didn't happen if I assign the searchbar as table view's `tableHeaderView`. It only happens when searchbar is in navigation title. Anyone know why?

Comment: mate, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318740/strange-white-space-at-uitableview-header-when-using-uisearchcontroller-with-uit It's helped me.

Comment: This answer fixed my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28722390/742298

Answer (score 10):

Apparently`automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is getting deprecated.

> 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use UIScrollView's contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior instead

So I would suggest doing something like:

```
searchResultsController.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

It worked like a charm for me. Some useful documentation:

[contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior)

[UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewcontentinsetadjustmentbehavior)

Comment: i am facing the same problem, but setting `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never` not working :(

Comment: it works like a charm in case you use `UITableViewController` as a searchResultUpdater not a `UIViewController` containing a `UITableView` in it.

Comment: Any solution for TableView in UIViewController?

Comment: @AlizainPrasla You should use something like this then  tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 120, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue to me:

```
searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

Answer (score 0):

write this in `viewDidLoad` :

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: This is `true` by default and I didn't touch this. I want to use transparent navigation bar and tab bar so I have to keep this `true`

Answer (score 0):

This problem can appear only for iOS 10. Write this in viewDidLoad

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 44, 0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5, try this. It worked for me

```
searchResultsController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.top
```